# I need assistance in parsing a JSON file to a .csv file using jq

Tags: json, jq

OK, so this is the fairly simple JSON source file which needs to be parsed...

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "meta": {
    "count": 10
  },
  "data": {
    "1040918564": [
      {
        "statistics": {
          "wins": 166,
          "battles": 441
        },
        "mark_of_mastery": 1,
        "tank_id": 9505
      },
      {
        "statistics": {
          "wins": 154,
          "battles": 325
        },
        "mark_of_mastery": 1,
        "tank_id": 47105
      }
    ],
    "1040836357": [
      {
        "statistics": {
          "wins": 216,
          "battles": 490
        },
        "mark_of_mastery": 1,
        "tank_id": 47105
      },
      {
        "statistics": {
          "wins": 114,
          "battles": 254
        },
        "mark_of_mastery": 2,
        "tank_id": 7969
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to end up with the following output which can then be piped to @csv and output to my .csv file....

```
[
  1040918564,
  166,
  441,
  1,
  9505
]
[
  1040918564,
  154,
  325,
  1,
  47105
]
[
  1040836357,
  216,
  490,
  1,
  47105
]
[
  1040836357,
  114,
  254,
  2,
  7969
]
```

My first step is `.data | to_entries[]` which parses as follows....

```
{
  "key": "1040918564",
  "value": [
    {
      "statistics": {
        "wins": 166,
        "battles": 441
      },
      "mark_of_mastery": 1,
      "tank_id": 9505
    },
    {
      "statistics": {
        "wins": 154,
        "battles": 325
      },
      "mark_of_mastery": 1,
      "tank_id": 47105
    }
  ]
*** snip ***
```

This is where I'm stuck. How do I include the "key" value into each element of the "value" array to achieve my desired output.

If I ignore "key" and use 'to_entries' on the "value" array, it almost does the job, but not quite...

`.data | to_entries[] | {id: .key, value} | .value | to_entries [] | .value | [.statistics.wins, .statistics.battles, .mark_of_mastery, .tank_id]`
gives....

```
[
  166,
  441,
  1,
  9505
]
[
  154,
  325,
  1,
  47105
]
[
  216,
  490,
  1,
  47105
]
[
  114,
  254,
  2,
  7969
]
```

which is as close as I have been able to get.

I'm getting too old for this and would really appreciate some help.    :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very conservative approach:

```
.data
| to_entries[]
| [.key]
  + (.value[]
     | (.statistics | [.wins, .battles])
       + [.mark_of_mastery, .tank_id])
```

Comment: Spot on!.... parses the entire file quickly and efficiently. I need to break it down to that I can understand the logic, but many thanks for your assistance.